# rails devise user external api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to setup a newsletter signup procedure when a new user signs up. I am using Mailchimp via gibbon to handle the newsletters. I have added a subscribe attribute to my model and a getter and setter method. I also have added the subscribe checkbox to my form. What I need to do is if the form box is checked subscribe the user to the email on creation.

model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable



  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :subscribe

  validates :username, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  has_many :contest_entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

  def subscribe=(join)
    puts "called subscribe with #{join}"
    if join
      Gibbon.new.list_subscribe(:id => "blah", :email_address => self.email)
    end
  end

  def subscribe
    subscribe ||= false
  end

end
```

Form view

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %></p>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :subscribe, "Subscribe to Newsletter?" %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :subscribe, :checked => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I was hoping that by adding the attr_accessible and a method it would call the api from the contoller automatically, but it does not seem to be called.

Any advice on how to handle this? I could also use advice on how to test with RSPEC to make sure it is being called.

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the issue. The problem was with the check for join inside the setter method. Since it was a checkbox, I needed to check for a matching integer of 1.

```
def subscribe=(join)
begin
  if join.to_i == 1
    gb = Gibbon.new
    result = gb.list_subscribe(:id => "blah", :email_address => self.email)
  end
rescue
  false
end
```

end